# Errors in running a file in NetBeans 6.5.1

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I've got this "CustomerLogin" application that i designed using NetBeans 6.5.1. The code shows no errors. But it still doesn't run. It shows some things in the output space on the bottom of the screen. What are all these? What should I do?
Here's what is displayed in the output window:

```
init:
deps-jar:
compile-single:
run-single:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:167)
        at CustomerLogin.initComponents(CustomerLogin.java:65)
        at CustomerLogin.<init>(CustomerLogin.java:22)
        at CustomerLogin$3.run(CustomerLogin.java:151)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

This is the code that shows error:

```
jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/user-login_icon.png"))); // NOI18N
```

Comment: My guess is that the path for the image of the icon at line 65 of your `CustomerLogin` class isn't right. It probably returns `null`, a invalid path to an image or a file that isn't an image. Can you provide the code that throws the error (actually a little more, like from line 55 to 75 of `CustomerLogin` for good measure).

Comment: this line showed error: 'jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/user-login_icon.png"))); '

Comment: When you say, "this code shows no errors", that is incorrect - there is clearly an error - the exception you've pasted above. What you probably mean is the code has no compilation errors.

Comment: @RobinGreen yes, the code I've entered by myself has no errors but there seems a problem with the image I used in the form. Are .png images acceptable in NetBeans?

Comment: @LuluLala the problem has nothing to do with NetBeans, the problem relates to the Java class called `ImageIcon`, as you can see in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The image is in a file on the desktop. I've used the same file to import it on to the form. – LuluLala 1 min ago`

From that comment, what you'll need to do is copy the image you want in your project, somewhere like `scr/main/java/resources/images` and then get that image, from your project folder, for your icon. That will change the path that Netbeans generate to a valid one.

I doubt you got your desktop folder as a source folder for your project, meaning the image isn't in your project `jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code cannot find the file at `/user-login_icon.png` on the `CLASSPATH`.

That's why you are getting a `NullPointerException` - because there is no such resource (null).

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just new to this kind of programming. Could you please tell me how do I fix this error?

Comment: You are telling it to find the file in the wrong place, or with the wrong name. Where is the file?

Comment: The image is in a file on the desktop. I've used the same file to import it on to the form.